# Questions About P, NP, languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, formal-grammars

I'm trying to get a better grasp of computation theory, and have a few questions that I can't seem to find great answers too.

1. Given language L, which is non-recognizable, is L* context free?
2. Is P countably infinite, and why?
3. Are all recognizable languages NP-complete?

Comment: One question per post, please!

Answer (score 1):

1.) Every context free language is decidable. CFL are not unrecognizable. Refer [1](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/ko/pdfs/lecture-15.pdf)

2.) P is countably infinite because P is the class of decision problem that can be solved on a deterministic turing machine in polynomial time. Every turing machine can be thought of as a finite string over some finite alphabets but all possible set of turing machines are countable infinite hence P is also countably infinite.

3.) NP complete languages are recognizable. A NP Complete languages can be found by modifying the halting problem which is just another form of halting problem(NP-Complete). Halting problems are undecidable but recognizable hence all NP-Complete problems are recognizable. Refer [2](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse322/04au/Lect10.pdf) fro details.